# how to pass variables to an include file from every parent file laravel

Tags: laravel

i am an absolute beginner in laravel so far i have created a basic structure of my website in laravel, there are some views in **resources/views** now there is a folder inside view named as includes and inside that folder there is a file named as `banner.blade.php` now this banner is included in almost every file which is in **resources/views** what i want to do is pass a variable containing the name of the banner and echo that variable inside the banner file. here's my code

**this is the parent blade from where i need to send a variable e.g $banner_name="contact us"**

```
@extends("app")

@section("content")

    @include("includes.banner-others")
```

**and this is my banner-others file**

```
<div class="banner-others">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>{{"uneeb"}}</h1>// i need to echo the $banner_name here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller where you call this view, you can pass a variable through like:

```
public function index()
{
    $banner_name = 'something';

    return view('your.view.name', compact('banner_name'));
}
```

You also could do it through view composer in AppServiceProvider.php:

```
view()->composer('your-view', function ($view) {
        $banner_name = 'something';
        return $view->with('banner_name', $banner_name);
    });
```

And via route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('your-view', ['banner_name' => 'Something']);
});
```

Comment: actually there is no controller right now! i am just using routes

Comment: it worked just one last question i worked with ci for over an year now and in ci its quite simple like $data['banner_name']="contactus";$this->load->view("include/banner-others",$data);  can we do something like this in laravel?

Comment: Id of suggested using ComposerServiceProvider instead of AppServiceProvider as it doesn't have to be tied to a route.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to pass variable. when you include a blade inside a parent blade, you can access parent's variables inside included one.

Comment: i tried that before asking the question it didn't work